# How to implement 404 pages in next.js

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, next.js13

In my project, I have the following folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

In the `/[...catchAll]/page.js` file, I have such a logic that checks if there exists any content at the desired URL, and if not, it returns a message: "This page does not exist.". Here is the code:

```
import PageTransition from "@/components/PageTransition";
import { pageContent } from "@/utils/content";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function CatchAll() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const blocks = pageContent?.[pathname];

  return (
    <>
      {!blocks ? (
        <PageTransition>
          <main>
            <h1>404 NOT FOUND</h1>
            <p>
              This page does not exist. Please check the URL and try again.
            </p>
          </main>
        </PageTransition>
      ) : (
        <>
          {blocks.map((block, index) => (
            <block.component {...block.componentProps} key={index}>
              {block.content}
            </block.component>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

My focus is the 404 part, since my logic returns `200 OK` although there is no such a URL. I want it to return `404`. How should I implement this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using next js version 13 and above a simple `not-found.js` file can be created in your app directory or src directory if that is being used.

[image: Next js 13+ 404 not found page]

By default this is a server component but can be marked async to fetch and display data. Also no props can be passed in this component.
src: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

Comment: Yeah it works. For the newcomers, just in case, this function is also mandatory to added.  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found

Answer (score 0):

If You want to Implement a Custom 404 Page and 404 Page in Nextjs ( App Router ).
Here is a Screenshot for Folder Structure.
*[ Image for not-found.js   mean 404 Page not found ]*

***src  ( app ) ( not-found.js )***

```
import React from 'react'
const notfound = () => 
{
  return (
    <div className="h-screen w-screen bg-gray-100 flex items-center overflow-hidden">
    <div className="container flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center px-5 text-gray-700">
        <div className="max-w-md">
            <div className="text-5xl font-dark font-bold">404</div>
            <p className="text-2xl md:text-3xl font-light leading-normal">
                Sorry we couldn't find this page.
            </p>
            <p className="mb-8">But don't worry, you can find plenty of other things on our homepage.</p>

            <button className="px-4 inline py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-5 shadow text-white transition-colors duration-150 border border-transparent rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue bg-blue-600 active:bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700">back to homepage</button>
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-lg">
        <h4>IMAGE HERE</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  )
}

export default notfound
```